# Flash - textfield not instancied , need eventlistener to tell me when the class is created

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Im creating a game in Flash and I have a class that have some text fields that I need to populate in this case a highScore. I get this error.

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Meaning that the object doesn´t exist , for some reason.

```
if (highscore.data.hard != null){ 
    highscore_txt.text= String( highscore.data.hard);. 
}
```

The highscore_txt I have created it , on the design view , meaning timeline.

I have other textfield, that I acess like the score and dont have any problem, this is problable because is acessed and I try to write to the textfield in the constructer of the class. I have done some tests and if I populate the field after all the constructer stuff is done , it works, like when I click some place and call that function using a eventlister.

what can I do , so that only after the class is completed initialized I insert the data in the textfield, is there any event that is listening for the class endes to create itself??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an event Listener in your constructor that listens to the ADDED_TO_STAGE-event :)

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, yourFunctionToPopulate);

private function yourFunctionToPopulate(e:Event):void
{}
```

Comment: Thanks man. more a less what I needed I just need to add the this.addEventLister  , so it knows we are refering to the class being created and added to the stage , and then  is just add the info I need.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Debugger in your Flash Builder (or other IDE) and set breakpoint to the first line of your code. Then check if `highscore` isn't `null`, `highscore.data` isn't `null` too.

Or you can change your code to be the following:

```
if (highscore && highscore.data && highscore.data.hard)  
{ 
    highscore_txt.text= highscore.data.hard.toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the highscore_txt textfield in the same MovieClip the class is attached to, and you have :

```
public var highscore_txt : TextField;
```

somewhere in the class, you should be waiting for the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE before doing anything with the elements. You can read about all the events [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bindable variable using [Bindable] annotation.  In your text field reference the bindable variable such as below.

```
[Bindable]
var myBindableVar:String = "";
</script>

<mx:TextInput text="{myBindableVar}" />
```

Now when you update the var, your text field value will auto-update.
You'll need to fix the syntax, but you get the idea?

Comment: Thanks that is in the Flex sdk, Im using flash sdk, there is no mxml or bindable stuff

Comment: hmm...I think you can do [Bindable], but assigning the bindable value to the text field would also be done in actionscript.  

highscore_txt.text = myBindableVar.

I have imported the Flex sdk swcs into the Flash Authoring tool to use the power of Flex's libraries (Flex 3.5 or 4.0).  It can really help out.